# Java Program to Count Words and Spaces Separately but this program shows : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: java, count, cpu-word

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CountWords_Spaces {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      String str = "Hello World";
      int i = 0, w = 0, s = 0, l, j = 0;
      l = str.length();
      for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
         if (str.charAt(i) != ' ' && str.charAt(i) != '\t') {
            w++;
            while (str.charAt(i) != ' ' && str.charAt(i) != '\t') {
               i++;
            }
         }
         s++;
      }
      s--;
      System.out.println(str.charAt(1));
      System.out.println("No of Words: " + w);
      System.out.println("No of Spaces: " + s);
   }
}
```

Comment: Code seems incomplete. Post complete code.

Comment: Your inner while loop is incrementing `i` without checking to see if its value exceeds `str.length()`

Answer (score 0):

Every time you increment `i` you must **test** that you have not passed the length of the input `str`. Change

```
while (str.charAt(i) != ' ' && str.charAt(i) != '\t') {
```

to include a test for `i < l` like

```
while (i < l && str.charAt(i) != ' ' && str.charAt(i) != '\t') {
```

With that one change I get

```
e
No of Words: 3
No of Spaces: 2
```